# Divide input fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, field

I have 3 input fields:

```
<input type="text" id ="v0" onkeyup="calculate()"><br>
<input type="text" id ="v1" onkeyup="calculate()"><br>
<input type="text" id="result" onkeyup="calculate()" readonly><br>
```

What I am trying to do is to count number from 1st input divided by number from 2nd input and displaying it in 3rd input.

```
function calculate(){
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var el, i = 0, total = 0; 
  while(el = document.getElementById('v'+(i++)) ) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/\\D/,"");
    total = total + Number(el.value);
  }
  result.value = total;
  if(document.getElementById('v0').value =="" && document.getElementById('v1').value ==""){
    result.value ="";
  }
}
```

Code is working fine for ADDING this input values, but I need to DIVIDE values from input fields.
I tried to replace "+" with "/" but it breaks the functionality.

Comment: Replacing `+` with `/` will not subtract for sure!!!

Comment: How to DIVIDE then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simpler approach like this:

```
function calculate () {
  var input1 = document.querySelector('#v0').value;
  var input2 = document.querySelector('#v1').value;
  if (input1 && input2) {
    document.querySelector('#result').value = (input1 / input2).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use **"-"** for subtraction. But if you want to perform division the problem is that during the first iteration you have total as 0, and it would be:

```
iteration[1]: 0/anything = 0
iteration[2]: 0/anything = 0
and so on
```

So you if you want to perform division you need initial value for total, it has to be the 1st input.
Hope that helps.